# Search for chocolatey local package and get result as powershell object

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

Is there any function to use instead of using this command in powershell script?

```
choco search --local-only $package.name
```

The function needs to return a list/array of objects with name and version if they exist, I want to use that in a powershell script.

Executing this command only returns an array of strings which is not clean to use

```
choco search --local-only $package.name
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One suggestion would be to use the Chocolatey PowerShell Module which you can find here:

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/chocolatey/0.0.71

This will return a PowerShell Object for the results of a search, which you can then enumerate, filter, etc as required.

Answer (score 2):

```
Install-Module -Name chocolatey

Import-Module -Name chocolatey
```

This would be what you're looking for